# Why are bluetooth devices shown as paired, even though they are not even available?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

When you pair a two bluetooth devices (e.g., a sound system with your mobile phone), the mobile phone will forever list the sound system as a paired device, even if you're physically so far away (>10km), that it is obviously impossible that there is a connection betwen the two devices.

What is going on? Why is the device shown as paired? Is this just poor naming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Paired devices section list out the devices which are already paired with your device. i.e., just an entry. However, it doesnt matter paired device are actively in connected state. Even when the paired device is not connected currently, the paired device section will list out since it has been paired already. if it bothering, you may long press the paired device and delete it but you need to paired it again to transfer the files.

hope this helps!